# Trying to delete a doc Mongoose using findByIdAndDelete but im always getting back a null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

Trying to delete a doc Mongoose using findByIdAndDelete but im always getting back a null when I know the doc id am passing to the function exists in MongoDB
I've tried:
findByIdAndRemove
findByIdAndDelete
findOneAndDelete -> this with the code below deletes two docs rather than one!

```
async function deleteCourse(id)
{
    const result = await Course.findByIdAndDelete(id,(err, res) => {
        if (err){ 
            console.log(err) 
        } 
        else{ 
            console.log("Deleted course: ", res); 
        } 
    })


}


deleteCourse('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd')
```

Comment: You are using the callback version of `findByIdAndDelete` method and also awaiting it; Either use the callback version or don't pass the callback and just await the result of calling `findByIdAndDelete`.

Comment: Thanks Yousaf, all I had to do is remove the await for this to work with the callback

Answer (score 1):

As @Yousaf suggested, you dont need the callback function if you are using async/await function. Also use try/catch to have the same behavior.

```js
async function deleteCourse(id)
{

  try {
    const result = await Course.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    console.log("Deleted course: ", result);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err) 
  }
}


deleteCourse('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd')
```